# How to implement onclick in ResultCard and swap the div with another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactivesearch

I want to display the details of what's user clicks in the ResultCard.

I want to replace the divs contents (currently displayed results) with rendered html based on the result found in my elastic search cluster(res) when user click the url in the resultcard.

I tried adding onclick properties but nothing happens. Reactivesearch documentation don't list this attribute.

Of course, I could pass argument in the url properties of ResultCard and redirect user to another page but page would be reloaded completely (with the menus defined in index.js and the footer)

I think creating parent component with state mirroring the currently displayed children component in the div is the way to go.

But, how to run a javascript for setting the state when user click in the resultcard?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ReactiveBase, CategorySearch, SingleRange, ResultCard } from '@appbaseio/reactivesearch';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <ReactiveBase
        app="artists"
        url="https://admin:xxxxxxx@node1.searchevolution.com:9200"
        type="_doc">
          <div style={{ display: "flex", "flexDirection": "row" }}>
            <div style={{ display: "flex", "flexDirection": "column", "width": "40%" }}>
              <CategorySearch
                componentId="searchbox"
                dataField="nom"
                categoryField="occupations.keyword"
                type="artists"
                placeholder="Search for Artists, Painter, Sculptor, Photographs"
                style={{
                  padding: "5px",
                  "marginTop": "10px"
                }}
              />

            </div>
            <ResultCard
              componentId="result"
              dataField="nom"
              title="Results"
              from={0}
              size={6}
              pagination={true}
              onclick="alert('Message à afficher');"
              react={{
                and: ["searchbox"]
              }}
              onData={(res) => {
                return {
                  image: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA",
                  title: res.occupations,
                  description: res.nom,
                  url: "/details/" + res
                }
              }}
              style={{
                "width": "60%",
                "textAlign": "center"
              }}
            />
          </div>
        </ReactiveBase>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Expected result is to change the div content with the rendered html from another component (not still coded).

Answer (score 0):

The handler should be called `onClick` instead of `onclick` (Even though it looks like HTML, this is JSX, so handlers need to be camelCase).

Also, your code will not call alert unless you put it in curly braces (which tells JSX to execute code). One more thing: you want to wrap it in a function, otherwise the alert will be called when the component mounts, and not on a click.

```
onClick={() => alert('Message à afficher')}
```

EDIT: I think I misunderstood your question. If I'm understanding correctly, you're right and you want to handle the click in the `App` component. Something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    showResultCard = true,
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ showResultCard: false });
  }

  render() {
    <ReactiveBase>
      ...
      {this.state.showResultCard ? (
        <ResultCard onClick={this.handleClick} ... />
      ) : (
        <OtherComponent ... />
      )}
    </ReactiveBase>
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for clarification about the JSX syntax. You're right about it but when clicking nothing happened. I removed the line url: "/details/" + res for testing and replaced onClick line with your code

Comment: I don't know how to catch the click with the parent component or any other method (except for click on the url: , then we can browse to other page. I would prefer my app stays on the same page.

Comment: onClick={(e) =>  this.handleClick(e)}  and  handleClick(e) {
 console.log("blabla") 
  }

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood. I edited my answer, hopefully it helps!

Comment: thanks for your help . can't get it working. it seems the onClick is neverhandled by ResultCard

Comment: finally got it working by using ReactiveList component instead.

Comment: thanks for this.state.showResultCard conditional statement

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

finally got it working by using the base component ReactiveList instead ReactiveCard.

ReactiveCard onData callback function is an object with image, title, description and url fields. No way, to return something else. No way to use onClick property.

So, better use the base component and do some html and css myself

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ReactiveBase, CategorySearch, SingleRange, ResultCard, ReactiveList} from '@appbaseio/reactivesearch';


class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showResultCard : true,
        };

    }

  handleClick = () =>  {
      this.state.showResultCard ?
    this.setState({ showResultCard: false }) : this.setState({ showResultCard: true });
  }
    render() {
        return (
        <ReactiveBase
        app="artists"
        url="https://admin:xxxxxxxxxx@node1.searchevolution.com:9200"
        type="_doc">
         {this.state.showResultCard ? (
          <div style={{ display: "flex", "flexDirection": "row" }}>
            <div style={{ display: "flex", "flexDirection": "column", "width": "40%" }}>
              <CategorySearch
                componentId="searchbox"
                dataField="nom"
                categoryField="occupations.keyword"
                type="artists"
                placeholder="Search for Artists, Painter, Sculptor, Photographs"
                style={{
                  padding: "5px",
                  "marginTop": "10px"
                }}
              />

            </div>


                 <ReactiveList
                            componentId="result"
                            dataField="nom"
                            className="result-list-container"
                            size={5}
                            onData={(res) => <div>{res.nom}<button onClick={this.handleClick}>tttt</button></div>}
                            pagination
                            URLParams
                            react={{
                                and: ['searchbox'],
                            }}
                /> 
          </div> ) : (<button onClick={this.handleClick}>back</button>)}
        </ReactiveBase>
        );
    }

}

export default App;
```